# How to avoid marker clipping in Matlab while saving two axis figure to pdf?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have some trouble while exporting a two axis figure with Matlab to pdf. The following example code works great while creating the figure in Matlab. But in the generated pdf-file all my red markers on the x-axis get cut off (see screenshot). Curiously this problem only occures, when I use a two axis plot

[Here is a screenshot of my figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8Z5c.png)

```
fig = figure;
x = linspace(0,25);
y = sin(x/2);
marker = linspace(0,25,5);
yyaxis left
plot(x,y,'g');
hold on;
r = x.^2/2;

yyaxis right
plot(x,r,'b');
hold on;
plot(marker,0,'rx','Markersize', 8);

saveas(gcf,'myfigure.pdf');
```

Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: What markers? Can you explain better what is it missing?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm talking about the green "x"-marker in the right and left bottom corner of the figure which is cut off. The problem occurs with any marker on the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve come into this a handful of times, super frustrating. I’ve usually tried some of the below options, and eventually something works. Some things to try:

1. Print as a png, then convert to PDF with gimp or something of the like (where 300 represents 300 dpi):

   ```
   print(handle, savefilename, ‘-dpng’, ‘-r300’)
   ```
2. Print as a vector image with the painters renderer, then convert to PDF with gimp:

   ```
   print(handle, savefilename, ‘-depsc’, ‘-painters’)
   ```
3. Try changing the marker to a different shape, or size, or both (using for example: `'markersize', 3, 'marker', 's'`)

Good luck. Let us know what ends up fixing it!